# logistic regression coefs to excel formulation

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, excel

I have done a Logistic regression in r with 3 variables involving 1 interation:

```
lm(predicthead~vol+weekday*head, mydata)
```

weekday is a factor - 7 days of the week.

The coef values are :

```
    Estimate
(Intercept) -14.81119721
Vol 0.118819705
weekday2    -24.30795615
weekday3    -4.634180612
weekday4    -21.64229775
weekday5    0.607492058
weekday6    42.80131468
weekday7    19.16098601
heads   0.059934818
weekday2:heads  0.026481088
weekday3:heads  0.006665015
weekday4:heads  0.022825105
weekday5:heads  0.005045576
weekday6:heads  -0.041724212
weekday7:heads  -0.019254475
```

From my Understanding below is what I do in excel:

```
intercept +
(coef of vol * vol)+
(coef of corresponding week days) + #there no is value for weekday 1
(coef * head)+
(coef of corresponding weekday:head * head) #no value for weekday1 so it will be zero.
```

The sum of the above should be equal to predict() value - but I am not able to match it.
Could you please explain where I have done wrong in calculating predicthead value using excel?

Comment: Are you including the link function?

Answer (score 1):

By running a logistic regression model, the objective is to get the chance of a binary outcome based on the different predictor variables. Since the result is a chance, what is modeled is actually:

$$
log \left(\frac{P_{+}}{1 - P_{+}}\right) = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1} + ... + \beta_{n}x_{n}
$$

So the coefficients you get from R are the $\beta$ values.
The function you have so far in Excel computes correctly the right hand side (RHS) of the above equation, but to get the probability $P_{+}$, you need to solve the equation for it. Let's call the RHS, $\mathbf{Bx}$

$$
log \left(\frac{P_{+}}{1 - P_{+}}\right) = \mathbf{Bx} \\
\frac{P_{+}}{1 - P_{+}} = e^{\mathbf{Bx}} \\
\frac{1}{e^{\mathbf{Bx}}} = \frac{1}{P_{+}} - 1 \\
\frac{e^{\mathbf{Bx}} + 1}{e^{\mathbf{Bx}}} = \frac{1}{P_{+}} \\
P_{+} = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\mathbf{Bx}}}
$$

To your results, apply this transformation and you should get the same results as the predict function in R.

Comment: thank you.  I tried as you suggested, but the value is always coming as 1.  The excel function used is.1/(1+EXP(-RHSVALUE)) = the result was 1 only.

Comment: Hmm.. that seems odd. Is Excel rounding the results? Can you change the value to a decimal?

Comment: did that.  But the value should be about 85 - but the result is 1. I am not trying for the probability value, I am looking for matching it with the predicted value through excel

Comment: @surpavan are you adding all the applicable coefficients, including the intercept to RHSVALUE?  Also, if you're trying to predict the reference category you need to add the cooefficients for *all* categories.

Comment: @david25272, thank you.  as said in the question, I have added the product of the (coefficients & its corresponding variable) and intercept.

Comment: Are you multiplying `heads` by -14.81119721?  It should be `heads` * 0.059934818.

Comment: I am doing as you said : heads * 0.059934818 only.   -14.81119721 is just add without any multiplication, We are on the same line.  I will correct in the question - will replace the intercepts with coef values.